# Can you use a different html template for each system message email?

Tags: emails

Is it possible to use a different html template for each system message email?

Alternatively can you determine which system email is being sent from within the template that you can set in the Craft email settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively can you determine which system email is being sent from within the template that you can set in the Craft email settings?

Not currently, but in the next ([post 2.3.2644](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2644)) release, there will be an `emailKey` variable available to the template so you can see which email is being sent.

Comment: Beat me to it!! :)

Comment: Haha... just my OCD kicking in. :)